# Expected ; before ... C++ Object of a class

Tags: c++

i know that somewhere there is a thread with such a question , but it did not helped me really much  Thats why . I have my class :  and my main and i dont know why it still gives me this error

Class :

```
class MyTime {

 public:
 MyTime(int =0 , int = 0 , int  = 0); // constructor
 void setTime(int , int , int); //set hour , minute,seconds
 void setHours(int); //set hour after validation
 void setMinutes(int); //set minute after validation
 void setSeconds(int); //set seconds after validation

//get function
 int getHours();//return hours
 int getMinutes();//return minutes
 int getSeconds(); //return seconds

 void printUniversal(); //output time in universal time format
 void printStandard(); //output time in standart time format

 private:
  int hours;  // 0-23(24 hour clock format)
  int minutes; // 0 -59
  int seconds; // 0-59

};
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyTime t1;
    MyTime t2(2);
    MyTime t3(21,34);
    MyTime t4(12,25,42);
    MyTime t5(27,67,78);

  cout<< "Constructed with:\n\nt1 : default \n";
  t1.printUniversal();
  cout<<"\n";
  t1.printStandard();
  cout<<"t2 \n";

  t2.printUniversal();
  cout<<"\n";
  t2.printStandard();

  cout <<"\nt3\n";
  t3.printUniversal();
  cout<<"\n";
  t3.printStandard();

  cout<<"\nt4\n";
  t4.printUniversal();
  cout<<"\n";
  t4.printStandard();

  cout<<"\nt5\n";
  t5.printUniversal();
  cout<<"\n";
  t5.printStandard();
  cout<<endl;


  }
```

function file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;

//Time constructor initializes each data member to zero
//ensure that Time objects start in a consistent state
MyTime::MyTime(int hr,int min,int sec){

  setTime(hr,min,sec); //validate and set time
}


//set new time value using universal time, ensure that
//the data remains consistent by setting invalid values to zero
void MyTime::setTime(int h , int m , int s){

 setHours(h);//set private field hours
 setMinutes(m); //set private field minutes
 setSeconds(s); //set private field seconds
}

void MyTime::setHours(int h){
  hours = (h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0 ; //validate hours
}

void MyTime::setMinutes(int m){
  minutes = (m>=0 && m < 60 ) ? m : 0; //validate minutes
}

void MyTime::setSeconds(int s){
  seconds=(s >= 0 && s < 60)? s : 0; //validate seconds
}

int MyTime::getHours(){
  return hours;
}

int MyTime::getMinutes(){
  return minutes;
}

int MyTime::getSeconds(){
  return seconds;
}
// print time in universal time (HH:MM:SS)
void MyTime::printUniversal(){
  cout << setfill('0') <<setw(2) <<getHours() <<":"<< setw(2)<<getMinutes() <<":" <<setw(2) <<getSeconds();
}

//print ime in Standard time (HH:MM:SS PM/AM)
void MyTime::printStandard(){
  cout<< ((getHours() == 0 || getHours() ==12) ? 12 :getHours() % 12)
  <<":" <<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<getMinutes()
  <<":" <<setw(2)<<getSeconds()<<(hours <12 ? "AM" : "PM");
}
```

The error will be that  expected ; before  t1,t2,t3,t4 .

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Did you include the header?

Comment: I don't suppose you included the header `MyTime` is defined in within your `main()` source file ?

Comment: can you pleas post the exact text of your error?

Comment: Yes i included the header file  in the main cpp

Comment: MyTime was not declared in this scope 
expected ; before t1
expected ; before t2
expected ; before t3
expected ; before t4
expected ; before t5

Comment: Is `MyTime` declared in some namespace and you forgot to qualify it in `main`? (And please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and edit your question including the exact error message, thanks!)

Comment: Well no , MyTime is just the class name .

Comment: I will make some modifications .

Comment: Ah... "time.h" :Isn't there a system file called that?  Try renaming the file to mytime.h...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename your 'class' files from `time.h/time.cpp` to `mytime.h/mytime.cpp`

There's a system include file called `time.h` and - depending on the include file search order configured for your compiler it's *possible* that the system file is being included in  preference to your one. So the compiler never sees your `MyTime` class at all.